# Exception: Conversion of Google Drive documentto application/pdf failed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google App Script cannot convert sheet to PDF. The sheet has a hidden sheet in it but I don't think that should be affecting anything.I get this error code "Exception: Conversion of Google Drive documentto application/pdf failed."

````
function savePDF() {
  var sheetName = "PDF_Sheet";
  var spreadSheetMain = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  if (spreadSheetMain){
    var pdfBlob = spreadSheetMain.getAs('application/pdf');
    var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);
    var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HbK3qAxb9yB7FpvpCm7uh_w5HU344y-2");

    destinationFolder.addFile(pdfFile)
  }

}```
````